# Is there a way to force reload an iframe from a different origin on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, iframe, mobile

I am building a simple Google Maps/Calendar tool for a sports league website. It loads one of several calendars in an iframe based on which map marker was clicked. This works well on desktop, though in Firefox it does cause a series of warnings in the console:

```
    Content Security Policy: The page’s settings observed the
    loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”). A CSP report is being sent.
```

On mobile, the default (main) calendar loads properly as the page loads. On tapping a map marker, the iframe's content disappears but does not reload the new calendar. Is there a way to force reload an iframe from an external source for mobile devices? I've experienced the same errors on an iPhone XR, iPhone 8, and Samsung S7 in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox browsers.

I've attempted to force a reload using the Location.reload method. This doesn't work as it requires the iframe to be same-origin. I also attempted the following code snippet I found on stack overflow for a related issue:

```
    document.getElementById('cal').src += '';
```

where #cal is the id for the iframe itself. This caused no change in functionality.

Finally, I've played with modifications to Content Security Policy using a meta tag in the document's . I am able to get some CSP errors to cease by including Google's domains (googleapis.com, google.com, etc.), but I am causing an equal number of errors by accidentally blocking other website resources (I do not know what I am doing with this tag.) The tag currently looks like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' maps.googleapis.com fonts.googleapis.com calendar.google.com; frame-src https://calendar.google.com https://accounts.google.com">
```

Which I know is wrong and insecure and messy and everything else, but I'm just trying to get something to work so I can work my way backward and solve the root of the problem.

The relevant code used to create this map/calendar tool is as follows:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="capture"><iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?mode=AGENDA&amp;height=500&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=example.com_mgj0i3q12ang1as82p8ggf3fuc@group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23691426&amp;ctz=America%2FVancouver" style="border-width:0" width="500" height="500" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //begin by building map. change element ID and vars as needed.



    var map;

    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.876837, -119.461071),
            zoom: 11,
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
            styles: [{ /*removed for brevity */ }]
              }
            ]


        });


        /* set location marker variables within this array of arrays (name, lat, long, calID). Called by the marker constructor based in array index */


        markers = [
            ['Parkinson Sports Fields', 49.88264, -119.46045, 'example.com_ee05ufe760mls53v7i8juk21hc@group.calendar.google.com'],
            ['Rutland Sports Fields', 49.89953, -119.38019, 'example.com_kkp2n6a430b5hp1nsneins9rko@group.calendar.google.com'],
            ['Mission Sports Fields', 49.83979, -119.47623, 'example.com_9b03spb4qm2alg3g3kqhn7sols@group.calendar.google.com'],
            ['Rosewood Sports Field', 49.87567, -119.56956, 'example.com_d2837h2fnv0f5aon52hfisuev8@group.calendar.google.com'],
            ['Shannon Woods Sports Field', 49.8669, -119.60595, 'example.com_dg3t7cph204esc98qeq81egk4s@group.calendar.google.com']
        ];
        var marker, i;
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]),
                title: markers[i][0],
                label: {
                    text: markers[i][0],
                    fontSize: "12px",
                    fontWeight: "bold"
                },
                map: map,
                icon: markerIcon,
                calURL: '<iframe id="cal" src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?mode=AGENDA&amp;height=500&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=' + markers[i][3] + '&amp;color=%23691426&amp;ctz=America%2FVancouver" style="border-width:0" width="500" height="500" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>'
            });

            //Attempts to smoothly zoom on marker click. Currently buggy; exploring resolutions.

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
                for (z = 1; z < 16; z++) {
                    map.setZoom(z)
                }


                /* this section replaces the iframe in the schedule div with the individual field's calendar. */


                var calsec = document.getElementById('capture');
                calsec.innerHTML = this.calURL;
                document.getElementById('cal').src += '';


            });

        }
```

The script continues, but this section contains the relevant parts: marker constructor, constructor array, and onclick function to zoom in on the chosen field and swap out the event calendar.

Comment: maybe you can remove and add the iframe again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ducmai commented, the answer turned out to be embarrasingly simple; By adding the line

```
calsec.innerHTML = null;
```

before inserting the new calendar iframe, the calendar loads slightly slower (1 second or so delay on refresh), but now displays on all devices!

Also, I needed to set every calendar to public. Most were, but some returned an X-Frame error as I had forgotten to properly set up the calendar.